# I want to write a function that opens a series of files and copies some of the data into an array

Tags: php

I want to write a function as a lot of this code is repeated but I am having trouble passing the name of the file and the mode as a parameter to the function.

```
        name = array();
        dob = array();
        address = array();
        data = array();

        #get name data
        $handle = fopen('data/name.txt', 'r');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $data = explode(':',fgets($handle, 1024));
            $name[] = $data[1];
        }
        fclose($handle);

        #get dob data
        $handle = fopen('data/dob.txt', 'r');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $data = explode(':',fgets($handle, 1024));
            $dob[] = $data[1];
        }
        fclose($handle);

        #get address data
        $handle = fopen('data/address.txt', 'r');
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $data = explode(':',fgets($handle, 1024));
            $address[] = $data[1];
        }
        fclose($handle);
```

This is what I've written so far as a function.

```
        function get_data($file, $mode, $array) {
        $handle = fopen("'" . $file . "'", "'" . $mode . "'");
        while (!feof($handle)) {
        $data = explode(':',fgets($handle, 1024));
        $array[] = $data[0];
      }
```

So I want to be able to call the function on each file, such as;

```
      get_data ('data/name.txt' , 'r', $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is almost correct :) Just two mistakes

- You didn't call `fclose()` inside your function
- You tried to enclose a string twice, where one is enough

  ```
  function get_data($file, $mode, $array) {
     $handle = fopen("'" . $file . "'", "'" . $mode . "'");
     #               /\ these       /\ and these are unnecessary

     while (!feof($handle)) {
     $data = explode(':',fgets($handle, 1024));
     $array[] = $data[0];
  }
  ```

  Just calling `fopen($file, $mode)` is ok :)
- If you would like to use your `$array` variable outside of your function, please remember to return it. If you add `return $array;` to the end of your function, you will be able to go:

  ```
  $result = get_data('file.txt', 'r');
  ```

PS: There is already a similar function in PHP, [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), perhaps you could use it? :)